# How to inject contructor in viewmodel witch contains filed parameters?

Tags: android, repository, viewmodel, dagger-hilt, inject

I have viewmodel, and repsitoryImpl class.

RepositoryImpl has parameter.

```
class RepositoryImpl (
  private val service: Service
) : Repository {
}
```

ViewModel class:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MessageFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor (
    private val repository: Repository = RepositoryImpl(......)
) : ViewModel() {
}
```

How can I inject RepositoryImpl

Comment: `class RepositoryImpl @Inject constructor (...)`

Comment: and ```private val repository: Repository = RepositoryImpl(service)```  ?

Comment: no, just `private val repository: Repository`.  Also make sure `Service` is provided by Dagger too.